# Fastapi : jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, fastapi

I am trying with the below code to redirect to login page using fastapi. I used TemplateResponse to redirect to index.html page which I already created inside the templates folder.

File structure as follows

```
- main.py
- templates -> index.html
- static
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def login_page(request :Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request":request})
```

I tried doing it but I am getting an error `"jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html"` and when I insert some HTML code statically it's working but TemplateResponse is not working properly. Even when I tried giving an entire path of the HTML file inside the templates folder it's giving a different error.

Please guide me on how to make this code work as I tried with different ways but in any case, this code is giving an error index.html template not found

Comment: Your code is running without issues on my machine (python 3.9.4, fastapi 0.63.0)

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem when I was doing unit testing and solved it as follows:

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=str(Path(BASE_DIR, 'templates')))
```

Comment: please use a code block (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with the following and it worked:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

I ran into that error this morning when running my own app with supervisord and gunicorn. I found that I had to dynamically set the template directory so that jinja2 knows where the files are:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory=os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser('templates')))
```

You could use Dependencies in FastAPI to redirect and force a user to login:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/